# Update list column dropdown value sharepoint

Tags: custom-list

I have a list in application http://webapp/sites/abc/listA
This list has field column 1. List has around 500 values as of now.

I have another list in different application http://webapp1/sites/xyz/listB
It has dropdown field BRD, i want all 500 values from listA to be updated in this dropdown field. Also if user add new value in listA column say 501th then should be auto updated in listB dropdown field. How we can achieve this by jquery. Thanks

Comment: too vague a requirement. try to better explain your scenario

Comment: Why do you wish to achieve this via jQuery? Or am I missing something here. You can achieve this using OOTB functionality of lookup columns. [Watch this video](https://youtu.be/ShLH0mBcA54) which guides you through creating lookup column.